# find rows with specific condition on the columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make an sql query where I will compare all rows to each other and check their columns. using condition I will display the need rows.

I made this one and I got an error message "UNKNOWN COLUMN" , any ideas how to fix it?

```
select * from table1 as tb1 where DATE_FORMAT(start_datetime, '%H:%i:%s') in (
    select DATE_FORMAT(start_datetime, '%H:%i:%s') from table1 as tb2
    group by DATE_FORMAT(start_datetime, '%H:%i:%s') having count(*) > 2 AND (end_datetime = start_datetime) OR (tb1.code = tb2.code)                                     
) AND user_id = 1
```

to explain what I wanna do,I'm searching the rows that have the same time then if the start_datetime is equal to the end_datetime or the rows have the  same code

in this 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTFuH.png) my sql query should return the last 4 rows, 2 because  they have the same start_datetime and end_datetime and 2 because the have the same time on the start_datetime , the same code and the end_datetime is NULL

Comment: Please update with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I updated my question with an example from my database

Comment: can you check if `tb1.code` column is actually present in table 1.

Comment: tb1 is table 1, tb2 is table 1 , the same table actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "union all" operator between 2 data sets

```
    select code,start_datetime,end_datetime from table2
    where  start_datetime=end_datetime

    union all

select t2.code,t2.start_datetime,t2.end_datetime from 
    (
    select code,start_datetime,end_datetime from table2
    where  start_datetime!=end_datetime
    and end_datetime is null    
    ) as t2
inner join ( select code table2 group by DATE_FORMAT(start_datetime, '%H:%i:%s'),code having count(*)>=2 )as t1 on t2.code=t1.code
```

Comment: not exactly what I wanted but I'm trying to modify it.

Comment: @if you shared dataset of your source table and expected output i think i will help you  a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding any errors we can't see because you haven't provided the schema, "fs1.code" and "fs2.code" do not seem to reference table aliases that have been defined in the statement.  The aliases that do get defined are "tb1" and "tb2" and they don't match.

Comment: ah sorry I miss tape it . I updated my question , actually the problem is when compare "tb1.code" with "tb2.code"